# Is it necessary to use a specific switch controller for a flyback converter circuit?

Tags: switching, controller

For example, this [DA2077](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/597/da2077-463478.pdf) is labeled as design for use with the [NCP1027](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/308/NCP1027-D-84808.pdf) switching controller. I have some [TNY290](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/328/tinyswitch-4_family_datasheet-217694.pdf) switches I order a while back but did not use. I do not see any problem with using the TinySwitch, but wanted a second opinion.

Comment: No but it is necessary to match/adapt the magnetic parameters to the 132kHz switch frequency gain Aux ratio etc for the TNY290

Answer (score 1):

You have answered your own question, as the DA2077 transformer **is** directly compatible with the NCP1027 PWM controller.

The DA2077 is **NOT** directly compatible with the simplistic TNY290 PWM controller.

The reason is the boost winding the transformer has to self-power the PWM IC once it starts up. This isolated winding also isolates the high voltage from the output voltage.

Both the DA2077 and the TNY290 detect the output voltage using an opto-coupler for isolation, connected to the 5 volt output.

To some degree these PWM IC's are flexible with their designs, but not pre-made transformers where the winding ratios are fixed.

To put it another way, the transformer *could* be used with the TNY290, but its output voltage and efficiency cannot be determined to be safe or as expected. There would be one winding not used. The transformer may not work properly at the 132 KHZ frequency the TNY290 puts out. This frequency is fixed internally to the IC.

Here is a quote from the DA2077 document:

> The DA2077-AL flyback transformer has been specifically developed for
> use with ON Semiconductor’s NCP1027 Standby Power Supply for ATX
> Applications and is specified in Application Note AND8241/D.

This is a quote from the TNY290 documentation:

> **Oscillator**
>
> The typical oscillator frequency is internally set to an
> average of 132 kHz. Two signals are generated from the oscillator: the
> maximum duty cycle signal (DCMAX) and the clock signal that indicates
> the beginning of each cycle.

Comment: Able to briefly review your answer? Suspect you may have mixed up the controller models and transformer model. Want to make sure I am reading what you intended to say correctly.

Comment: @A.S. Thank you for pointing out a major FUBAR on my part. It has been fixed.